# Can I triangulate complex or non-manifold geometry in a consistent pattern?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, faces

I need help, I'm trying to make a Model like Hyrule Field of TLoZ OoT, but I don't have idea to make that triangles like in the picture, I tried to create a grid and press Ctrl + T, but it doesn't look like this.

[image: It's Hyrule Field from The Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time]

Comment: I'd like to think it's more likely the map maker(s) started with a subdivided and triangulated plane instead of triangulating after *or* you can manually select the "clean" flat parts and work forward. Would also like to point out that unless you're going for a specific lowpoly material look, this is pointless as a game engine will triangulate the model and if rendering normally this won't be noticed much if at all.

Comment: So, if I use squares, it's basically the same if I use triangles?

Comment: See my answer here [Why is the view header showing triangle count when my mesh is all quads?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9250/why-is-the-view-header-showing-triangle-count-when-my-mesh-is-all-quads) and yes, triangles are difficult to work with also.